# Avoid requesting or executing remotely hosted code (including by referencing remote javascript files or executing code obtained by XHR requests)

Tags: chrome-extension, расширения

Уважаемые коллеги, помогите прояснить один вопрос. При попытке разместить в Интернет-магазине Хром свое расширение мне выдается следующее предупреждение - Avoid requesting or executing remotely hosted code (including by referencing remote javascript files or executing code obtained by XHR requests).
Смысл его в общем понятен, непонятно только на что грешить. У меня есть несколько версий:

1. В popup.html есть строка `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://withyouon.com/js/index.js"></script>`'
2. В background.js есть

   $.post("https://withyouon.com/server.php”, p, function(a)
   {
   d=eval(‘(‘+a+’)’);
   })

Я теряюсь в более конкретном определении проблемы. То ли она в том, что нельзя подключать js с удаленного сервера. То ли в том, что $.post не работает, хотя jquery.min.js берется из папки расширения (см. манифест ниже). И нужно использовать XMLHttpRequest.send()
То ли дело в eval(‘(‘+a+’)’);
В чем же конкретно проблема?

Манифест:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "withyouon.com",
  "version": "1.2",

  "icons": {
    "128": "icons/128.png",
    "129": "icons/konv.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
      "js": [ "/js/jquery.min.js", "/js/background.js", "/js/inject.js", "/js/script.js" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "description":"ver. 1.2. withyouon.com site extension ajax orient",
  "short_name": "withyouon.com site extension ajax orient",

  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/128.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },

   "background": {
        "scripts": ["/js/jquery.min.js", "/js/background.js"]
  },

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "web_accessible_resources": ["/js/jquery.min.js", "/js/inject.js", "icons/128.png", "popup.html", "/js/script.js"],   

    "permissions": ["activeTab", "proxy", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "\u003Call_urls>", "storage", "tabs", "webNavigation", "cookies", "<all_urls>", "history" ]
}
```

Может вся проблема в том, что секция permissions": должна содержать еще два значения - "https://withyouon.com/*", "http://withyouon.com/*" ? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Вы предположили верно, проблема в этом:

> То ли она в том, что нельзя подключать js с удаленного сервера...

Модераторы Chrome Web Store крайне не любят, когда расширение подтягивает сторонние JS. Согласно их рекомендациям, весь необходимый JS должен лежать либо в папке с расширением либо загружаться с публично-известных CDN (jQuery, bootstrap и т. д.).

Причина понятна: сегодня ваш скрипт хороший и добрый, а завтра хакер ваш ломает сервер и подменяет файл.

Рекомендую положить в папку и упаковать скрипт вместе с расширением.

Дополнение №1: 
Скорее всего у вас будут так же проблемы с исполнением кода (`eval`), полученного со стороннего сайта.